# Why does this pandas str.extract pattern work?

Tags: python, regex, string, pandas, text-extraction

I have a dataframe "movies" with column "title", which contains movie titles and their release year in the following format:

The Pirates (2014)

I'm testing different ways to extract just the title portion, which in the example above would be "The Pirates", into a new column.

I used pandas Series.str.extract() and found a regex pattern that works, but I'm not sure why it works.

```py
movies['title_only'] = movies['title'].str.extract('(.*)[\s]', expand=True)
```

The above code correctly extracts the "The Pirates" into a new column, but why doesn't it extract only "The" (everything before the first whitespace)?

Comment: `*` is a greedy quantifier, meaning it will match as far into the string as possible. To only match the first word, you can switch it to a lazy quantifier `*?`. Also, note that you don't need square brackets around the `\s`. `[\s]` == `\s`

Comment: @CAustin You could have written that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- is a greedy quantifier, meaning it will match as far into the string as possible. To only match the first word, you can switch it to a lazy quantifier *?. Also, note that you don't need square brackets around the \s. [\s] == \s

According to CAustin